# Draw a triangle at a specific Longitude and Latitude on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a triangle in meters at specific latitude and longitude. The example [Google give](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) is quite obvious on how to draw polygons, however it uses longitude and latitude to specify the points of the polygon.

Is there a way to draw a triangle/polygon at a specific lon/lat but specify the points in meters?
Like how you use the API to draw a circle at a long/lat point but specify the radius in meters.

Comment: What kind of triangle?  The specific lat/lon equals the centre of the triangle, one of the corners, the mid-point of the hypotenuse or what?

Comment: Something like you specifc a point in longitude and latitude and then that is the origin for a x/y coordinate plane, or you can then specifc lengths and bearings from that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert degrees to  meters with 1° ~  111 km at Equator.

As you go towards pole the lines of longitude converge and you will need to use the following table to compensate for this.

```
Degrees     Lat         Lng
0° Equator  110.574 km  111.320 km
15°         110.649 km  107.551 km
30°         110.852 km  96.486 km
45°         111.132 km  78.847 km
60°         111.412 km  55.800 km
75°         111.618 km  28.902 km
90° Pole    111.694 km  0.000 km
```